# Convert multidimensional array into comma separated group in json

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
array(7) {
  ["Locate"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "Self Set - Short"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Locate"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "1701"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Self Set - Long"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Locate"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "1521"
    }
  }
  ["Step 1 - Campus"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "Self Set - Short"
      [1]=>
      string(15) "Step 1 - Campus"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "1471"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Self Set - Long"
      [1]=>
      string(15) "Step 1 - Campus"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "1239"
    }
  }
  ["Step 2 - Date"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "Self Set - Short"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Step 2 - Date"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "717"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Self Set - Long"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Step 2 - Date"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "607"
    }
  }
  ["Step 3 - Time"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "Self Set - Short"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Step 3 - Time"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "508"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Self Set - Long"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Step 3 - Time"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "436"
    }
  }
}
```

I am exporting it as json using this:

```
$data = array();
foreach( $group as $key => $value ) {
    foreach($value as $key2) {
        $data[] = array(
            'event' => $key,
            $key2[0] => $key2[2],
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode( $data );
```

My current output is:

```
[{"event":"Locate","Self Set - Short":"1698"},{"event":"Locate","Self Set - Long":"1515"},{"event":"Step 1 - Campus","Self Set - Short":"1469"},{"event":"Step 1 - Campus","Self Set - Long":"1230"},{"event":"Step 2 - Date","Self Set - Short":"717"},{"event":"Step 2 - Date","Self Set - Long":"603"},{"event":"Step 3 - Time","Self Set - Short":"508"},{"event":"Step 3 - Time","Self Set - Long":"433"},{"event":"Submit Button","Self Set - Short":"343"},{"event":"Submit Button","Self Set - Long":"309"},{"event":"Reschedule - New","Self Set - Short":"18"},{"event":"Reschedule - New","Self Set - Long":"21"},{"event":"Reschedule - Keep","Self Set - Short":"3"},{"event":"Reschedule - Keep","Self Set - Long":"3"}]
```

I need it to export like this:

```
[{"event":"Locate","Self Set - Short":"1698", "Self Set - Long":"1515"},{"event":"Step 1 - Campus","Self Set - Short":"1469","Self Set - Long":"1230"},{"event":"Step 2 - Date","Self Set - Short":"717","Self Set - Long":"603"},{"event":"Step 3 - Time","Self Set - Short":"508","Self Set - Long":"433"},{"event":"Submit Button","Self Set - Short":"343","Self Set - Long":"309"},{"event":"Reschedule - New","Self Set - Short":"18","Self Set - Long":"21"},{"event":"Reschedule - Keep","Self Set - Short":"3","Self Set - Long":"3"}]
```

The end result needs to take the two sub arrays and comma separate them with the main array key instead of creating to groups per set I need 1. Any help would be great!

Comment: your values in json is changed from your original array? is that typo mistake or some calculation happening?

Comment: Also final json have some more value which is not there in the initial array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your initial array i have written this code:-

```
<?php

$data = array(
  "Locate"=>array(
        0=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Short",
          1=>"Locate",
          2=>"1701"
        ),
        1=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Long",
          1=>"Locate",
          2=>"1521"
        )
    ),
    "Step 1 - Campus"=>array(
        0=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Short",
          1=>"Step 1 - Campus",
          2=>"1471"
        ),
        1=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Long",
          1=>"Step 1 - Campus",
          2=>"1239"
        )
    ),
    "Step 2 - Date"=>array(
        0=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Short",
          1=>"Step 2 - Date",
          2=>"717"
        ),
        1=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Long",
          1=>"Step 2 - Date",
          2=>"607"
        )
    ),
    "Step 3 - Time"=>array(
        0=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Short",
          1=>"Step 3 - Time",
          2=>"508"
        ),
        1=>array(
          0=>"Self Set - Long",
          1=>"Step 3 - Time",
          2=>"436"
        )
    )
);
  echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);
  $final_data = array();
  foreach ($data as $dat){
      foreach($dat as $key=>$value){
          $final_data[$value[1]]['event'] = $value[1];
          $final_data[$value[1]][$value[0]] = $value[2];
      }

  }
 $final_data = json_encode(array_values($final_data));
  echo ($final_data);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/555678

**Note:-**

**1. Your values in your desired `json` is changed from your original array?**

**2. Also final `json` have some more value which is not there in the initial array.**

**Check yourself and correct. Thanks**

Comment: Thanks Anant, that is exactly what I needed. I marked this as answered. After looking at this data on the chart I now realize I need to do a bit more work because instead of the total value, I really need the percentage from step to step. So essentially I would need Step 2 - Date / Step 1 - Campus and convert to percent in order to get funnel from step to step. Can this be working into your logic?

Answer (score 0):

Better late, than never...

Here is a more direct way to process your data that doesn't need to leverage temporary associative keys (to be deleted later).

- Use a `foreach()` loop and declare the `groupname` and the dual-row `set` of data.
- Push into your result array (`$data`) a one-dimensional array consisting of the hardcoded first element `event` with the `groupname` value AND the dynamically generated associative elements (which have keys derived from the `0` column values and values from the `2` column values).
- The `+` is just a concise / function-less version of `array_merge()` that works as intended on associative elements.
- This is clean and clever because it uses `array_column()` for the reason it was added to PHP and the output array is instantly ready to `json_encode()` as soon as the loop is finished.
- Furthermore, this approach doesn't bother overwriting identical `event` data within an inner loop; and this approach will function as intended even if you add more rows to the `$set`s.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CDWH4))

```
$group = [
    "Locate" => [
        ["Self Set - Short", "Locate", "1701"],
        ["Self Set - Long", "Locate", "1521"]
    ],
    "Step 1 - Campus" => [
        ["Self Set - Short", "Step 1 - Campus", "1471"],
        ["Self Set - Long", "Step 1 - Campus", "1239"]
    ],
    "Step 2 - Date" => [
        ["Self Set - Short", "Step 2 - Date", "717"],
        ["Self Set - Long", "Step 2 - Date", "607"]
    ],
    "Step 3 - Time" => [
        ["Self Set - Short", "Step 3 - Time", "508"],
        ["Self Set - Long", "Step 3 - Time", "436"]
    ]
];

foreach ($group as $groupname => $set) {
    $data[] = ['event' => $groupname] + array_column($set, 2, 0);
}
//var_export($data);  
echo json_encode($data);
```

Output:

```
[{"event":"Locate","Self Set - Short":"1701","Self Set - Long":"1521"},{"event":"Step 1 - Campus","Self Set - Short":"1471","Self Set - Long":"1239"},{"event":"Step 2 - Date","Self Set - Short":"717","Self Set - Long":"607"},{"event":"Step 3 - Time","Self Set - Short":"508","Self Set - Long":"436"}]
```

Comment: If you need a calculation to be performed, you should have mentioned this in your original question.  Assisting with this question extension will require you to express your exact expected output, but this should be posted as a new question.  (I assume that you sorted this issue out years ago)